# compatibility level during migration from 2008 R2 to 2014

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, migration, sql-server-2014

I'm working on a project to create tools for our project teams to use to quickly spin up development and test environments having some or all our 20+ databases, but with only the specific data they need for their project. The environments may be physical servers, VMs or local instances on the developer's computer. The production DBs are all 2008 R2 but we will be moving to 2014 so we need to support both.

I'm developing a script to create a standard set of logins and database users with specific roles assigned. These will necessarily be version specific to account for the role-related 2008 stored procedures that have now been deprecated. The specific databases each team restores will vary, so the script uses a cursor over sys.databases and does its work in a WHILE loop having a USE at the top and a FETCH NEXT at the end.

Most of the DBs have is_auto_update_statistics_async set to 0, but a few, including everyone's default database, have it set to 1. As a result, the USE statement will change the SET context that existed when the cursor was allocated causing the FETCH NEXT to fail. My first attempt to correct that was to issue SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATS_ASYNC ON right before the FETCH NEXT, but that resulted in error - even on a 2014 local instance ('AUTO_UPDATE_STATS_ASYNC' is not a recognized SET option).

I have a solution for that, but while researching I noticed that the compatibility_level was the same (100) in both the original 2008 R2 databases, and in the databases restored to a 2014 local instance.

Does the error, and the fact that the compatibility level remained the same, indicate the databases were not really migrated when they were restored to the 2014 instance?

If so, would incrementing the compatibility level after the restore correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell in your post, it is likely that it's just a syntax error, firstly it's `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` and not `AUTO_UPDATE_STATS_ASYNC`.

Secondly, `SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` is not a valid SET option (like `ANSI_NULLS` etc), it is an `ALTER DATABASE` setting, so should be executed as so:

```
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON
```

Comment: Doh!
I did have AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC in the script but should have used ALTER. Thanks!